# Abstract data types in a type class definition

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what's happening with the type `s` below:

```
class A a where
    f :: a -> s

data X = X

instance A X where
     f x = "anything"
```

I expected this to work, thinking that since type `s` isn't bound to anything, it could be anything. But the compiler says that it "Couldn't match expected type ‘s’ with actual type ‘[Char]’", as if type `s` was a fixed type like Int, Char…

So my second interpretation was to say that, since we don't know anything about `s` in the type class declaration, we cannot tell when making `X` an instance of `A` if the return value of the function `f` we give matches type `s` or not. But there are type classes that use abstract data types that are not bound to anything without problems, like Functor:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Why is the type `s` above a problem when types `a` and `b` here aren't?

Comment: By writing `f :: a -> s`, you say to the compiler that the "user" of the function can decide what to use, not the `instance` of `A`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to express this:

```
    f :: a -> ∃s . s
```

...but what the signature you've written says is actually

```
    f :: a -> ∀s . s
```

What does all of that mean?

- The *existential type* `∃s . s` means, the functions may return a value *of some type*, i.e. “there exists a type `s` such that the function returns an `s` value”.
  This is not supported by the Haskell language, because it turns out to be pretty useless.
- The *universal type* `∀s . s` means, the function is able to produce a value *of any type*, i.e. “for all types `s`, the function can return an `s` value”.

The latter is *very* useful; `fmap` is actually a good example: that function works, no matter what types `a` and `b` are, and the user is always guaranteed that the result will actually have the desired type, namely `f b`.

But that means you can't just *pick some particular type* in the implementation, like you did with `String`. ...Well, actually you *can* do that, but only by wrapping the existential in a data type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, UnicodeSyntax #-}

data Anything = ∀ s . Anything s

class A a where
  f :: a -> Anything

instance A X where
  f x = Anything "anything"
```

...but as I said, this is almost completely useless, because when somebody wants to *use* that instance they'll have no way to know what particular type the wrapped result value has. And there is nothing you can do with a value of completely unknown type.

Comment: So if I get it right, writing `f :: a -> s` in the type class means that it must be possible to use the return value of `f` anywhere a Int or a Char or anything else is expected. Both the following must work: `("a" ++) . f` and `(1 +) . f`. But then writing `f x = "anything"` would break the second example, and this is why it's impossible.

Comment: Exactly, that's how it is.